# C# Restsharp not working

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to make a post request with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org).

```
var request = new RestRequest("login", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("email", email); 
request.AddParameter("password", password);

List<RestResponse> result = null;

var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<result>(request, response => {
    MessageBox.Show(response.Data.Name);
});
```

But I receive the error:

> 'result' is a variable but it's used like a type.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try researching the error. You're trying to use a variable as a generic type argument. You'll need to provide the type that you want the response to be deserialized into.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't compile, as you've noticed.

Without knowing anything about your model, or the response coming back, I'm going to take a guess that this may get you closer to where you want to be.

```
List<RestResponse> result = null;

result = client.ExecuteAsync<List<RestResponse>>(request, response => {
    MessageBox.Show(response.Data.Name);
});
```

This *at least* compiles, because we're passing a **type** into `ExecuteAsync` rather than a **variable**

Answer (score 2):

Error is saying it clearly.
You need to give type instead of variable name result, similar to the following:

```
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<List<RestResponse>>(request, response => {
MessageBox.Show(response.Data.Name);
});
```